# PHP unit returns after PHP ends proces

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm still messing around with php Unit where I found the following scenario:

I have the following code to update a simple user profile which works fine.

```
public function updateUserData($sessionId, $first_name, $last_name, $email) {
    $result = $this->_instance->executeQuery('
        UPDATE users SET email=?, first_name=?, last_name=? WHERE users_id=?'
        , array($email, ucfirst($first_name), ucfirst($last_name), $sessionId)
    );

    if($result){
        Session::set('detailsUpdated', '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Succes! </strong>Your details have been updated!</div');
        Redirect::to('profile.php');
    }
}
```

The problem is, I can't really return anything that I can base my UnitTests on. I'm unable to return a true or false because if I do so, after the redirect it doesn't execute and if I do it before the redirect it doesn't execute the redirect anymore.

How can I make a return that I can pickup with a test?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem arises because the method does things that is not supposed to do. If the method is supposed to update the user data, why would it do a redirection afterwards?

Is it impossible that in the future you will need to do this data update but instead of redirecting, do another action?

Just get rid of the `if` part and return the update result. Redirections should be performed from controllers, not from data libraries.

Comment: Allright, I will have to find another way to set my redirections. Is it allright to set a session within the data lib?

Comment: Generally, I'd say it's not a good idea. The reason is that the library knows how to do some operation, and the controller knows why that operation is being done (user data coould be updated by the user itself or by a cron script, in which case error messages could be different and sessions would be employed or not.